# Deployment .woff and woff2 files to SAP system

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-web-ide

I want to deploy my web app from Web IDE to SAP system but I've got problems with a custom font.

```
OTS parsing error: Size of decompressed WOFF 2.0 is less than compressed size
```

I think it's because in SE80 the woff and woff2 files aren't in MIME folder. **The .eot is in MIME folder**.

What I've tried so far:

- Added `.Ui5RepositoryBinaryFiles` to my project.
- Edited the repositorypathmappingfile.xml. .woff and .woff2 entries because they were wrong. The property internal_rep was "B" instead of "M" like in the .eot entry.
- I've imported the files manuallly in SE80 (Import MIME object)

I use this ui5.yaml script for building:

```
specVersion: '1.0'
metadata:
  name: myApp
type: application
resources:
  configuration:
    propertiesFileSourceEncoding: UTF-8
builder:
  customTasks:
    - name: webide-extension-task-updateManifestJson
      beforeTask: generateManifestBundle
      configuration:
        appFolder: webapp
        destDir: dist
    - name: webide-extension-task-updateNeoApp
      afterTask: generateVersionInfo
      configuration:
        destDir: dist
        appFolder: webapp
        nameSpace: zApp/myApp
    - name: webide-extension-task-lint
      afterTask: webide-extension-task-updateNeoApp
      configuration:
        destDir: dist
        appFolder: webapp
        nameSpace: zApp/myApp 
    - name: webide-extension-task-resources
      afterTask: webide-extension-task-lint
      configuration:
        nameSpace: zApp/myApp
```

Any ideas? How to deploy the files as binary to MIME folder?

Comment: Is there a mime type in the system for fonts? https://help.sap.com/doc/7b7a606d728810148a4b1a83b0e91070/1610%20002/en-US/frameset.htm?e2397ad300794aa5a084552e66654881.html

Comment: I've added *.woff2. Deleted .woff2 file - Deployment - Added .woff2 file - Deployment. Still wrong folder :-(

Answer (score 1):

No solution found, but it works with a workaround. Unlock objects in transport in SE03. Delete and recreate BSP in SE80 and upload app via `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD` in SE38 with `.Ui5RepositoryBinaryFiles` file in webapp folder.

Content:

```
^.*\.ttf$
^.*\.otf$
^.*\.less$
^.*\.svg$
^.*\.eot$
^.*\.woff$
^.*\.woff2$
^.*\.ico$
```